# Too many automatic redirections were attempted (even CookieContainer fail)

Tags: c#, php

c# code:

```
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
CookieContainer cook = new CookieContainer();
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
HttpWebRequest myRequest =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://website.com/index.php");
myRequest.Method = "POST";
myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
//myRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)";
myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
Stream newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
newStream.Close();
//myRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
myRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
WebResponse response = myRequest.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
newStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(newStream);
Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

index.php

```
$num= $_POST["num"]; 
echo $num;
```

the above code work for me before but suddenly it fail. I tried everything
adding `CookieContainer()`, setting Redirection to false, using other code for httprequest.

If I `AllowAutoRedirect` set to false the result would be:

---

302 Found

Found
The document has moved here

---

But when i tried this to other web-hosting server it works. So i was thinking its on my WHM/cPanel? Also i have already white-listed my Ip. Already check .htaccess and the options in my cpanelb(redirection).

So any ideas what might cause this?

*note: i have already disable'd cloud flare protection*

Comment: anyone? This only happen a week ago. Does CloudFlare has somthing to do with this? Because I install the plugin in all the domains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already Found the solution. It was when they updated my WHM and some Rule was added in ModSecurity Tool that I was not aware off. I just disable that and everything was back to normal :)